# How update just specific cell in primefaces dataTable

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm creating a dynamic datatable full of input fields. Sometimes when user insert values in some inputs, an specific cell should be updated, and only this cell. I thought it could be simple, but yet didn't make it work.
The cell I want update is "valor total", this cell should be updated when the value of two others cell change:

[image: cell to update]

**EDITED**

[image: js chrome]

I've tryied f:ajax with complete id and got "Component with id:lancamentoNF:popupLancamentoNF:tabelaItensNF:0:valorTotalItem not found". Changed to p:ajax and no errors happen but it doesn't update!!

```
<h:panelGroup id="painelItensNF" layout="block" styleClass="hrgi-div-form aba-lancamento-nf clearfix" style="overflow:auto;">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="width: 1700px;">
        <p:dataTable id="tabelaItensNF" value="#{modeloTabelaDinamicaItemNF.itens}" var="itemEmbrulhado" styleClass="tabelaDinamica" height="174" style="width: 100%;" rowIndexVar="indice">
            ... (some columns)
            <p:column style="width: 5%"
                      headerText="quantidade">
                <hrgi:spinner id="quantidadeItem"
                              value="#{itemEmbrulhado.item.produto.detalheTributavel.quantidade}"
                              dinheiro="false"
                              fator="#{itemEmbrulhado.item.produto.detalheTributavel.unidadeFracionada?0.01:1}"
                              local="pt-BR" min="0.00" width="70">
                    <p:ajax event="change"
                            update="lancamentoNF:popupLancamentoNF:tabelaItensNF:#{indice}:valorTotalItem"
                            listener="#{controladorPopupLancamentoNF.calcularValorTotalItem(itemEmbrulhado)}" global="false" />
                    <f:convertNumber
                            maxFractionDigits="#{itemEmbrulhado.item.produto.detalheTributavel.unidadeFracionada?2:0}"
                            minFractionDigits="#{itemEmbrulhado.item.produto.detalheTributavel.unidadeFracionada?2:0}"
                            locale="pt-BR"
                            for="quantidadeItem"/>
                </hrgi:spinner>
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="width: 5%"
                      headerText="valor unitario">
                <hrgi:spinner id="valorUnitarioItem"
                              value="#{itemEmbrulhado.item.produto.detalheTributavel.valorUnitario}"
                              dinheiro="true" fator="0.01" local="pt-BR" min="0.00" width="70">
                    <p:ajax event="change" 
                            update="lancamentoNF:popupLancamentoNF:tabelaItensNF:#{indice}:valorTotalItem"
                            listener="#{controladorPopupLancamentoNF.calcularValorTotalItem(itemEmbrulhado)}" global="false"/>
                    <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencyCode="BRL" currencySymbol="R$ "
                                     maxFractionDigits="10" minFractionDigits="2" locale="#{cc.attrs.local}"
                                     for="valorUnitarioItem"/>
                </hrgi:spinner>
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="width: 3%"
                      headerText="valor total">
                <h:outputText id="valorTotalItem" value="#{itemEmbrulhado.item.produto.valorTotal}">
                    <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencyCode="BRL" currencySymbol="R$ "
                                     maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2" locale="pt-BR"
                                     for="valorUnitarioItem"/>
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            ... (more columns)
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

It works when I update the panelGroup "painelItensNF" with complete id, but the focus is lost and user should find the input he was working to continue...

Comment: You should replace your accepted answer as this seems to be possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use `update="valorTotalItem"`. It's relative to the current row already.

So, replace

```html
<p:ajax ... update="lancamentoNF:popupLancamentoNF:tabelaItensNF:#{indice}:valorTotalItem" />
```

by

```html
<p:ajax ... update="valorTotalItem" />
```

Comment: It didn't work... Just using complete id without row index works

Comment: It has always worked for me. Which JSF impl/version and PF version are you using?

Comment: Okay, that'll be MyFaces. In the future questions please always mention exact impls/versions.

Comment: Please how update all cells in a row, this approach  works  when the h:inputtext has id and  id is unique. Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi @BalusC, I'm using primefaces 5.3 with jsf 2.1 and this solution does not work for me (I'm updating h:outputLabel using a p:remoteCommand). how can I solve it ? thanx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to update a single cell. It's id is autogenerated, so you can't update this component by id. 
You can try switching to primefaces 3.3 (not final release yet, but you can start working with the snapshot), and try if you can do what you want using primefaces selectors: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectors.jsf

you'll have more changes with that, but I'm not sure if you'll be able to do it.

Or, you could update the panel and add some javascript to set the focus to the appropiate component. execute the javascript in the "oncomplete" method of the p:ajax component.

EDIT:
Remove the index from the update, so it looks like this: ":lancamentoNF:popupLancamentoNF:tabelaItensNF:valorTotalItem"
And of course BalusC is right, you may also just use "valorTotalItem"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added new picture showing the id follow a pattern. This project is dificult to change to primefaces 3 (I've already tried).

Comment: @brevleq try to update this: ":lancamentoNF:popupLancamentoNF:tabelaItensNF:valorTotalItem" (with no index, and starting with ":"). it wont throw exception, but I'm not sure what it's going to be updated. maybe the whole "valorTotaItem" column. let me know what happens

Comment: Thanks @Damian, the approach of removing index worked! I don't understand why, but worked... Please change the answer so I can mark as solved :)