# refreshing one item in datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am having problem with next situation:
I have one datatable on my list page, and when I click on 'update' item it goes to update page. After update is finished it come back to list page.

My problem is: "how can I refresh only that item in datatable(list)"?

Comment: can you give us some code please

Comment: Usually you can't just refresh only one row of Datatable. Please explain clearly with some code!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636324/how-update-just-specific-cell-in-primefaces-datatable and @KishorP look this to update just one row

Comment: I have one bean with method getAll()
with for example:
someList = someObject.getAllItems()

In data table I have link to edit that goes to edit_page, 
After editing, i click save, it saves object and goes back to list page, but my datatable is still populated with old files, because, first i check is someList empty or not.
I would like to update only edited object, not to getAllItems again