# Primefaces update cell value of a editable Datatable taking value from a dialog

Tags: primefaces, datatable, dialog, auto-update

I have a requirement like this:

1. Display an editable table(implemented)
2. In the edit mode, display a button next to the first cell of the row(implemented)
3. on click of the button, open a dialog.(implemented)
4. Dialog will have a data table with radio buttons. (implemented)
5. Select one row and click on save button on the dialog. (implemented)
6. on the dialog, selected row's first cell value should come and sit as the cell value of the home screen's editing row (the one displayed in point#2).

I could implement all the points mentioned above except the point# 6. On click of save button on the dialog, dialog closes as expected but it is not updating on the home screen's editing cell.

if someone can provide a code snippet to exactly update the editing row's cell, that will be a great help!

Comment: What ahve you tried? Can you post the code you wrote for the point#6?

Comment: You can´t update just cell you can only update all datatable. Read [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636324/how-update-just-specific-cell-in-primefaces-datatable