# update cell from primefaces datatable after action invoked

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'd like to update a single column from my primefaces datatable after clicking on a button in that row.

My jsf page:

```
<h:form id="visitForm">
        <p:dataTable id="visitTable" var="visit" value="#{visitBean.findAllVisits()}" rows="2"
                     paginator="true" lazy="true">
            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['clearance']}"
                      sortBy="#{visit.maritimeDeclarationOfHealth.clearance.status}" id="clearance">
                <p:commandButton value="#{msgs['clearance.ok']}"
                                 actionListener="#{visitBean.changeClearance(visit)}" global="false" update="clearance"/>
            </p:column>
    </p:dataTable/>
</h:form>
```

My visitBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class VisitBean implements Serializable {

    ...

    public void changeClearance(Visit visit) {
        visit.changeClearance();
    }
}
```

The visitService changes the clearance from OK to NOK but my datatables column isn't changed. Any ideas?

Primefaces 5.2

I've looked at [How update just specific cell in primefaces dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636324/how-update-just-specific-cell-in-primefaces-datatable) but this doesn't seem to solve it.

Comment: The link you posted is about updating something that is **around** a full datatable. No wonder it did not solve your issue ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by not updating the column but updating an element in that column:

```
<p:column headerText="#{msgs['clearance']}">
  <p:outputPanel id="clearance">
     <p:commandButton value="#{msgs['clearance.ok']}" actionListener="#{visitBean.changeClearance(visit)}" 
      global="false" update="clearance"/>
  </p:outputPanel>
</p:column>
```

Comment: That is not a 'fix', it is doing it as it is meant to be. ;-) It is precisely as you mentioned it: _"but my datatables **column** isn't changed. "_ You refered to a column id, not to the content at that time. And the link you posted in your question is about updating something that is **around** a full datatable. No wonder it did not solve your issue.