# How to block a single datatable cell in primefaces with blockUI

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm creating a datatable with some some dynamically generated columns. In each of the cells of those columns, there's a button to refresh the data of that specific cell.

What I want is that the cell is blocked when the button on that cell is pressed.

Sample code:

```
<p:dataTable id="table" var="tableVar" value="#{tableValues}">
    <p:columns id="column" var="columnVar" value="#{columnValues}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value ="#{columnVar}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="Some Text"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Button Text"
                         id="button"
                         update="table"
                         actionListener="#{some.method()}"/>

        <p:blockUI block="?????" trigger="button">
            <p:graphicImage name="loading.gif"/>
        </p:blockUI>
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

I don't know what should go in the `block` parameter to only block a cell. I also tried to just `block="column"`, but even that wasn't blocking the column as I expected, instead it was just displaying the loading gif near the button but not blocking anything.

I have seen this question [How update just specific cell in primefaces dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636324/how-update-just-specific-cell-in-primefaces-datatable) where the answers say it's not possible to specify a single cell, but it's from 2012, and the answers mention that it might get fixed on a later version.

Comment: Just as a comment, I would also like to have a button on the header that blocks and refreshes the entire column, but I expect that if I can solve this problem I'll be able to solve the other one.

Creating a question for that other question seems a little bit spammy, but if someone can help me with that I wouldn't want their answers to be buried in comments, or as answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

After playing a bit, I found a solution.

You can define a `<p:outputpanel id="cell"></p:outputpanel>` surrounding the content of the cell, and then block it with `block="cell"` in the blockUI component.

The result would be something like:

```
<p:dataTable id="table" var="tableVar" value="#{tableValues}">
    <p:columns id="column" var="columnVar" value="#{columnValues}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value ="#{columnVar}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <p:outputpanel id="cell">
            <h:outputText value="Some Text"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Button Text"
                             id="button"
                             update="table"
                             actionListener="#{some.method()}"/>

            <p:blockUI block="cell" trigger="button">
                <p:graphicImage name="loading.gif"/>
            </p:blockUI>
        </p:outputpanel>
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```